# Stuck at hypothesis testing assignment

Tags: statistics

So I have this assignment in statistics that states the following:

We need to either accept or throw away a big package of processors. Because of quality control we take take a sample of 200 processors and find 24 that are not working.

The maker of the processors claims that in the entire package there are at most 10 processors that are not working. Do we have enough evidence to throw away his statement with a confidence level of 4%.

I assume this is a Hypothesis Testing question with the formula being equaled to:

### ***z*** ***=*** $\frac{p - po}{\sqrt{\frac{po(1-po)}{n}}}$

I can see that ***n = 200*** however I don't know what is ***p*** or what is ***po***

Is ***p = $\frac{24}{200}$*** and ***po = $\frac{10}{200}$*** or is it the other way around?

Comment: You say you can see $n=100$.  Are there $100$ processors in each package? Or were the $200$ part of the package?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I mean to say ***n = 200*** Correcting it right away